# Filter Access Combobox Through Dropdown Menu

Tags: ms-access

[Sample ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s55qX.png)

Is there a way to create a combobox like the one shown in the mockup above? One where I can search/filter within the dropdown itself (red text in image), where the column headers would normally go (if enabled). I've been asked to create this specifically in our access database, and I'm not sure if it's possible. If this is possible, what combobox properties would need to be changed to make it happen?

Comment: No, combobox does not work that way.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: Why is typing in box not sufficient? Is AllowAutoCorrect property set to Yes? List is sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Typing in the box is sufficient to me, but my boss has a specific vision of the sample I provided instead.
The AllowAutoCorrect property is set to Yes, and it works, but it only autocompletes the "OC" JIRA key ID. If I search for the summary by typing in the box, autocorrect doesn't kick in. I workaround this by requerying on afterupdate, but I need to enter a string in the textbox and hit enter, then click on the dropdown button, and it'll be filtered by summary.

Comment: If you want AutoCorrect on other field, key would have to be hidden. Could have RowSource a UNION query that puts ID and Summary in same visible column so typing either will match item. Key field would also still be a hidden column.